# Excel Connectivity with SSAS - An error was encountered in the transport layer

Tags: pivot, excel-2010, ssas

I have a SSAS Cube in SQL 2012 to which I can connect from Excel 2010 without an issue using a windows user credentials. However whenever I restart the server hosting the cube and I try to refresh the pivot in the excel (in a client machine) it throws and an error saying "**An error was encountered in the transport layer**". I am then prompted to re-enter the password for the windows account I am using to connect to the data source.

The problem is that if I have couple of pivots open in different sheets in the same excel book per each pivot I am prompted to do this (even if I do a Refresh and not a Refresh All) which is bit of a trouble.

Is there a way to fix this or at least to make sure I have to enter the password only once and it will not seek for each and every pivot being refreshed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to connect to the cube under credentials which are not the credentials you used to log into your laptop, then the proper way of accomplishing this is the following. Create a new connection from scratch. (You can't modify an existing connection.) Do the following:

1. Data tab... From Other Sources... From Analysis Services...
2. Type in a server name, username, and password... click next
3. choose your database and click next
4. Check "Always attempt to use this file to refresh data". And check "Save password in file". Click Yes when the prompt pops up.
5. Click finish.

That will save your username and password (in clear text) into the odc file. (Be aware of this for security purposes.)

Based upon your description of the symptoms I suspect you didn't have these checkboxes checked when you created the connection. Thus it would continue to prompt for username/password when it needed to reconnect.

Comment: Yup I didn't do the "Save password in file" and "Always attempt to use this ...". Let me try that up. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Tried it but didn't work out. Still being prompted and only good thing is now I don't have to type in the password :D Thanks for the help though

Comment: But if you close and reopen Excel then it doesn't prompt you and successfully connects/refreshes automatically? If so then what you are experiencing is the expected behavior unfortunately. If it is connected and the connection drops because the server reboots then it shows that error. Let me know if I am understanding you right.

Comment: I thought so too. But it's prompting me whenever I close and reopen Excel and tries to refresh.

Comment: @Sam you created a whole new empty Excel file and a new connection from scratch with the checkboxes I mentioned and it is still doing that?

Comment: Haa !! So that's what I missed !!! Did it from scratch and the problem is gone. Interesting.. Thanks a ton @Greg !! Spared me quite a headache !!

Answer (score 0):

We had an issue which ended up being a saved password which was held in Credentials Manager, once this was corrected the pivot table could be refreshed

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was that the AD group did not have "Allowed to authenticate" permission on the SSAS server's computer object in AD.