# OLAP Cube Through Excel - Transport Layer Error

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas, olap

I have a cube running on SSAS SQL Server 2012.

Every time I want to connect to a cube, or update data in files that contain it, I (and all the other users) get the "Transport Layer Error" message.

I click "OK" and am prompted to re enter my credentials. Usually it works after that (though sometimes it doesn't).

This becomes very annoying when I need to refresh a file that contains a dozen of cubes: I need to enter the credentials 12 times.

Sometimes it becomes impossible to connect to the cube, I get stuck in a Transport Layer Error infinite loop.

Important note: The server is on a different domain than the PC, I am connected to it through a VPN.

Is there any way to get rid of this?

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715908/excel-connectivity-with-ssas-an-error-was-encountered-in-the-transport-layer

Comment: Try to make a whole new excel workbook and readd your connection to your cubes and see if it happens again

Comment: @plaidDK Oh my, that actually worked. Thank you! I did a quick search but didnt find that thread. Feel free to add it as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this to avoid problems again

1. Data tab... From Other Sources... From Analysis Services...
2. Type in a server name, username, and password... click next
   choose your database and click next
3. Check "Always attempt to use this file to refresh data". And check "Save password in file". Click Yes when the prompt pops up.
   Click finish.
   That will save your username and password (in clear text) into the odc file. (Be aware of this for security purposes.)

And if that doesnt help, try to create a whole new excel workbook and readd connections to the cube.